# Can't programmatically access WebConfigurationManager in VS 2012

Tags: system.web, webconfigurationmanager

In my VS 2012 project, I have a reference to System.Web.

If I browse System.Web in Object Brower, it contains System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager; but in my code, `System.Web` only shows me `AspNetHostingPermission`, `AspNetHostingPermissionAtribute`, `AspNetHostingPermissionLevel`...

In VS2010 I don't have this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since there is a code aspect to your question, what language are you using (e.g. C# or VB.NET)?  Your question should be tagged with it.

Comment: Is the code in question (i.e. the `.cs` or `.vb` file) exactly the same in VS 2010 and VS 2012?

Comment: I was wrong to make the reference ... I ask for an apology. System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigManager does exist and works just like always.

Answer (score 0):

In Object Browser, simply browsing System.Web will allow you to drill into all of `System.Web.dll`'s namespaces (e.g. System.Web.Configuration).

In code, however:

- You need a `using` statement (assuming C#) for each namespace in the assembly before IntelliSense will display the types within it (or the code can reference them).
- Your project's target framework (in the project's properties) also needs to be set correctly.

### `using` Statement

In the code file in question, it sounds like you may then have...

```
using System.Web;
```

...but not:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

In this case, add `using System.Web.Configuration;` to the code file.

### Target Framework

Another possibility is that your VS 2012 project's target framework (i.e. *Application* > *Target framework* in the project's properties) is incorrectly set to a .NET Framework *[client profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc656912(v=vs.100).aspx)* – for example...

> .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

...instead of:

> .NET Framework 4

Comment: I was wrong to make the reference ... I ask for an apology. System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigManager does exist and works just like always.